# some of the git commands stopped working on Windows

Tags: git, command-line-interface

Although i uninstalled and re-installed git for windows (2.27.0.windows.1) some of the git commands don't work.

```sh
git log 
'': : command not found

git config --list
'': : command not found
```

I'm able to see the git commit history on VS Code, git history or through WSL2 Ubuntu but not with git bash or cmd.

Comment: why did you uninstalled it in the first place? It might give some insight on the issue

Comment: and how did you uninstall, were there any error messages, and if so, what were they?

Comment: what do you mean "the commands don't work" are you talking about specific commands in VS Code? or do you mean via command line? I was assuming you were talking about strictly the cmd window until the last sentence.  are *none* of the git commands working in cmd, but they are in vs code?  if this is the case, it's probably just a matter of a missing path variable

Comment: i've simply used the appwiz.cpl on windows and uninstall the Git version, there were no error messages. Git log was was not returning any commit history

Comment: Kritner, i'm referring to cmd as you guessed it correctly and yes some of the commands doesn't work like the one i listed in the question body. But other git commands like git add, git status, git commit etc. works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I fixed the issue on my computer. just in case if someone else experiences the same issue, it was simple as running the below command.

```
 git config --global core.pager less
```